# Fullscreen image viewer with countdown on screen

Tags: kiosk

I'm trying to create a kiosk mode for Raspberry Pi, but I also want to be able to display a countdown (near the bottom) to a specific time like 9:00am and show itself like 0:00 or 00:00 respectively. The countdown needs to be independent of when the images change.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a viewer that already has this type of option?

I'm currently using feh which works for displaying the images, but has no way of showing the countdown. It would also be really nice to have the countdown automatically start and stop at different times, but I can work on that after I find a way to get it to show.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about taking it as a programming exercise? The Raspi is about education, after all. Though people seem to prefer python, I prefer Tcl. It's so simple.

TESTED. It works. Adjust the parameters as you like. The program takes a list of directories to search for image files on the command line. The "Img" package is not required if you stick to the built-in image formats of Tk.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh


## Load required packages.
package require Tk
package require Img


## Parameters.
set ::geometry 1920x1080+0+0
set ::steps 9
set ::font [font create -size 100]
set ::posx 0
set ::posy 0
set ::anchor nw


## Global variables.
regexp {^([[:digit:]]+)x([[:digit:]]+)\+} $::geometry match ::screenwidth ::screenheight
set ::currentimage {}
set ::currentimageindex 0
set ::files {}


## Get all images files in all given directories.
foreach dir $argv {
    lappend ::files {*}[glob -nocomplain [file join $dir *]]
}


## Start procedure.
proc start {} {
    ## Configure the viewer window.
    canvas .imagebox -width $::screenwidth -height $::screenheight
    .imagebox create image 0 0 -tags image -anchor nw
    .imagebox create text $::posx $::posy -tags counter -anchor $::anchor -font $::font 
    .imagebox raise counter
    pack .imagebox -fill both -expand yes
    wm geometry . $::geometry
    wm overrideredirect . true
    wm withdraw .
    wm deiconify .

    ## Load first image.
    nextimage
}


## Load next image.
proc nextimage {} {
    ## Delete current image.
    catch {image delete $::currentimage}

    ## Load next image.
    set fd [open [list |convert -resize ${::screenwidth}x${::screenheight} [lindex $::files $::currentimageindex] jpeg:-] r]
    fconfigure $fd -translation binary
    set ::currentimage [image create photo -data [read $fd]]
    close $fd

    incr ::currentimageindex
    if {$::currentimageindex>=[llength $::files]} {
        set ::currentimageindex 0
    }
    .imagebox itemconfigure image -image $::currentimage

    ## Countdown.
    nexttimerstep $::steps
}


## Next countdown step
proc nexttimerstep {countdown} {
    ## Set countdown text.
    .imagebox itemconfigure counter -text $countdown

    ## Check countdown.
    if {$countdown>0} {
        ## Update counter after one second.
        after 1000 [list nexttimerstep [expr {$countdown-1}]]
    } else {
        ## Load next image.
        nextimage
    }
}


## Start after Tk is initialized.
after 0 start

## Start Tk event loop.
```

Comment: Wow! Thats amazing, I've never even heard of TCL. I should have made myself more clear. I'm trying to countdown to a specific time. This code appears to only shows the very top left of the image... Also is there anyway to make this detect the screen size instead of declaring it? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get what kind of countdown you want.

Comment: I want a countdown that counts down to a time like 9:00am and shows the minutes, the countdown isn't for how long the image needs to be up but for something else. I edited my main question to be more clear for others.

Comment: To address your first problem, I've edited the source so it now uses ImageMagick to resize the image to the window size before loading it.

Comment: One *could* try to autodetect the geometry but as I have a dual screen setup, I cannot really test it. It's not so simple to get the geometry of individual monitors. Parsing the output of *xrandr* seems to be most simple.

Comment: So … this should be some kind of clock with a background image viewer?

Comment: Yeah, my end goal is to have this in my church on a tv in the lobby and it would cycle through announcements (images) and show when the service starts. That's why it needs to be able to countdown to specific time. What also gets tricky is we have three services so I'll have to make it so it shows the timer then when it hits zero disappear and re-appear after our service is over etc. but that's kind of hard to explain and I wanted to keep my questions simple

Comment: This is hardly something which already exists. What means, there's a price tag on creating it.

Comment: Yeah and most of the options I've seen are monthly subscriptions, which are the worst in general haha. So thats why I wanted to see if there was a simple solution to showing a countdown or text over an image.